# Solr : Write custom request Handler

Tags: solr

Well , I want to write custom request handler. So I thought of reviewing code of 'standard request handler' come with solr. 
Where can I find source code of handler. i didn't find it in my solr directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can view the source code of the StandardRequestHandler from this [link](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/branches/lucene_solr_4_2/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/handler/StandardRequestHandler.java?view=markup). The entire tree of the source code can be accessed in readonly view via http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/

I would encourage you to check out the [RequestHandler documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRequestHandler) on the Solr Wiki as well for reference and guidance.

Answer (score 1):

In order to create and use a custom request handler in solr you need to:

1. Write a class that extends from `SearchHandler` and handles the custom logic.
2. Update `solrconfig.xml` to add en endpoint that uses the custom request handler.

## Custom Solr Request Handler Class

```
public class MyCustomRequestHandler extends SearchHandler {

  @Override
  public void handleRequestBody(SolrQueryRequest solrRequest,
    SolrQueryResponse solrResponse) throws Exception {

    /// modify solr request object

    // let solr handle the modified request
    super.handleRequestBody(solrRequest, solrResponse); 

    // optionally modify solr response object
  }
}
```

## Solr configuration

```
<requestHandler name="/custom_endpoint"
  class="org.example.MyCustomRequestHandler" default="true">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
    <str name="wt">json</str>
    <str name="defType">edismax</str>

    ... rest of configuration

  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Comment: can you share some source code to reference? any github link ?