# Solr - custom request handler to handle streams by extending ExtractingRequestHandler

Tags: java, solr

We are migrating from GSA to Solr and are looking to keep the existing GSA Connectors to scrape our ECM systems. 
GSA Connectors construct XML documents as follows

```
<gsafeed>
    <header>
      <datasource>source</datasource>
      <feedtype>incremental</feedtype>
    </header>
    <group>
      <record url="..." displayurl="http://url.com/a/b" action="add" ...>
       <metadata>
       <meta name="Author" content="author@company.com"/>
       <meta name="DocIcon" content="pdf"/>
       ... bunch of other meta fields ...
       <content encoding="base64compressed">...</content>
      </record>
    <group>
</gsafeed>
```

**The `<content>` is not text but the document byte stream, compressed and then encoded to base64.**

What I need is for Solr to ingest this XML, will obviously needs to be modified first.

So I've come up with this process:

1. Code a custom request handler which GSA will send that XML to. This looks like a decent place to start: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40568514/482261
2. The custom handler will modify the incoming request body: (a) decode and then decrypt the `<content>` node data (b) construct a Solr-able XML
3. Forward this modified SolrQueryRequest to the /update/extract (class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler") handler for Tika extraction

I am trying to build the custom handler. Doing CRUD on the request parameters is easy enough, but I am lost on how to deal with content streams.

**Edit 1:**
Solution posted.

**Edit 2:**
I now have a follow up question. The posted solution works when GSA feed only has a single document. With multiple documents, each with their own metadata, things get a bit murky. I haven't decided on a way of dealing with that yet, once I do the solution will be posted as a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the what I have come up with to address the original question. Hopefully it helps someone.  I have extracted relevant bits from my working code, please treat this as pseudo-code.

```
public class MyCustomRequestHandler extends ExtractingRequestHandler {
@Override
    public void handleRequestBody(SolrQueryRequest originalReq, SolrQueryResponse rsp) throws Exception {

    Iterable<ContentStream> streams = originalReq.getContentStreams();
    ContentStream theStream = streams.iterator().next();
    InputStream is = theStream.getStream();

    //stream is an XML so parse it to a Document. I used the XOM library for this
    Document doc = parser.build(is)

    //process accordingly:
    // 1. Convert the <meta> tags to a Map<String, String>
    SolrParams extractedSolrParams = new MapSolrParams(/*Map<String, String> of all <meta> fields in GSA feed */);
    // 2. Take <content> and pass it to decodeUncompress() 
    byte[] decodedUncompressedContent = decodeUncompress(/* <content> from gsa feed*/) 

 //Once the parsing and processing is complete, construct a new solr request
      LocalSolrQueryRequest localRequest = new LocalSolrQueryRequest(originalReq.getCore(), extractedSolrParams);
     List<ContentStream> newContentStreams = new ArrayList<ContentStream>();
        newContentStreams.add(new ContentStreamBase.ByteArrayStream(decodedUncompressedContent, "GSA Feed <content>"));
        localRequest.setContentStreams(newContentStreams);

     super.handleRequestBody(localRequest, rsp);
  }

private byte[] decodeUncompress(byte[] data) throws IOException {
        // Decode
        byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(data);

        // Uncompress
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Inflater decompresser = new Inflater(false);
        InflaterOutputStream inflaterOutputStream = new InflaterOutputStream(stream, decompresser);
        try {
            inflaterOutputStream.write(decodedBytes);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            try {
                inflaterOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }
}
```